# Android sqlite update fails

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following table structure

```
public class DBConnectionTableTVShow {
    public static final String SHOWID = "show_id";
    public static final String SHOWNAME = "show_name";
    public static final String SHOWSEASON = "season_name";
    public static final String EPISODENAME = "episode_name";
    public static final String EPISODESTATUS = "episode_status";

    public static final String DBNAME = "entertainment_tracker";
    public static final String DBTABLE = "tv_show";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
}
```

Now i Want to update `episode_status`

I have created following method

```
public void updateEpisodeStatus(String showName, String seasonName, String episodeNo, String epStat) {
     db.execSQL("UPDATE tv_show SET " +
                "episode_status='"+epStat+"'"+
                "WHERE show_name='"+showName+"' " +
                "AND season_name='"+seasonName+"' " +
                "AND episode_name='"+episodeNo+"'", 
                null);
}
```

When I try to use this method I am getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs

How to resolve this?

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the second parameter that u r passing as `null` and it will work.

```
public void updateEpisodeStatus(String showName, String seasonName, String episodeNo, String epStat) {
     db.execSQL("UPDATE tv_show SET " +
                "episode_status='"+epStat+"'"+
                "WHERE show_name='"+showName+"' " +
                "AND season_name='"+seasonName+"' " +
                "AND episode_name='"+episodeNo+"'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use execSql for upading the data.It executes a single SQL statement that is NOT a `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`.

You should use a [Update Method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) to update the DB.

Answer (score 1):

use like that

String query= "update tv_show SET episode_status= epStat where show_name=showName and season_name=seasonName";
db.rowquery(query, null);